# Is it possible to compare day + month(not year) against current day + month in Python?

Tags: python

I'm getting data in the format of 'May 10' and I am trying to figure out if it's for this year or next.  The date is for only a year so May 10 would mean May 10 2015 while May 20 would be May 20 2014.

To do this, I wanted to convert the string into a date format and compare but without the year I'm getting this error:

> ValueError: unconverted data remains:

Here's a rough idea of my current approach:

```
if datetime.strptime(DATE_TO_COMPARE, '%b %d')  >  time.strftime("%d %m"): #need to figure out may 11 is for this year or next year. Year is not provided.
    print datetime.strptime(DATE_TO_COMPARE, '%b %d'), ' > ',  time.strftime("%d %m")
```

Is there a better way to do it? I'm thinking of making a dictionary of months and then converting the month into a number then adding it the day (i.e.Dec 5  = 512) and comparing it.  But not sure if there's a better way?

Comment: Maybe using epoc time https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse, then replace the year in the result (with [`date.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.replace) and test against today, *not* a string:

```
from datetime import date, datetime

today = date.today()
parsed = datetime.strptime(DATE_TO_COMPARE, '%b %d').date().replace(year=today.year)
if parsed > today:
    # last year
    parsed = parsed.replace(year=today.year - 1)
```

I used `date` objects here as the time of day shouldn't figure in your comparisons.

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import date, datetime
>>> today = date.today()
>>> DATE_TO_COMPARE = 'May 10'
>>> parsed = datetime.strptime(DATE_TO_COMPARE, '%b %d').date().replace(year=today.year)
>>> parsed
datetime.date(2014, 5, 10)
>>> parsed > today
False
>>> DATE_TO_COMPARE = 'May 20'
>>> parsed = datetime.strptime(DATE_TO_COMPARE, '%b %d').date().replace(year=today.year)
>>> parsed
datetime.date(2014, 5, 20)
>>> parsed > today
True
```

Comment: ahhh after posting this question I thought about this approach.  Adding today's year to my variable and see if its gone already and if it is then its for next year.  This answer is great and thanks for showing me the logic!!

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import date, datetime 

today = date.today()

print(today)

DATE_TO_COMPARE = 'Dec 16'

parsed = datetime.strptime(DATE_TO_COMPARE, '%b %d').date().replace(year=today.year)

print(parsed)

print(parsed == today)
```