# pandas create a new column based month and day?

Tags: pandas

I have a datefram `df` with `date` column:

```
date
2019-11-01
2019-11-02
2019-11-03
2019-11-04
2019-11-05
...
2021-04-01
```

. I want to create a new column `is_in_period` whose value is `True` if the `date` is locate in `(11-15)` to `(03-15)` of next year. Such as `df[df.date==pd.Timestamp('2019-11-17')]['is_in_period'] = True`.

Comment: It seems my post is not clear. If my `date` column is more than these 2 years. Is there a fast way to directly compare this time range without a specific year? Otherwise, I have to assign every year concluding `11-15` to `03-15`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that your date column type is `datetime64[ns]`. You can do this with

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

You'll also need to `from datetime import datetime` to use that library to make other dates to compare against

From here, you make your new column based off of your two comparisons

```
df['is_in_period'] = (datetime.strptime('2019-11-02','%Y-%m-%d') <= df['date']) & (pd.to_datetime(df['date']) <= datetime.strptime('2019-11-04','%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Comment: I tried this method before. But I had to specific the `year` to specify the period. I want to do this without a given `year`

Comment: @Whisht, ahh, I see that now. Yes, that's a bit trickier...

A non-elegant solution here, but could probably work - have a temporary column where you change the year on everything to some generic year (1900, say), and then do the comparison to be 'date-temp <= 3/15/1900 OR date-temp >= 11/15/1900'

Here is another answer that can maybe help with that:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704100/is-it-possible-to-compare-day-monthnot-year-against-current-day-month-in-p

Answer (score 0):

Firstly convert your date column to datetime[ns] dtype via `to_datetime()` method:

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

then get the current year and the next year:

```
currentyear=df['date'].dt.year[0]
nextyear=currentyear+1
```

Now create a boolean mask via `between()` method:

```
mask=df['date'].between(str(currentyear)+'-11-17',str(nextyear)+'-03-15')
```

Finally:

```
df['is_in_period']=mask
```